# Remove file path from url

Tags: php, apache

I don't want testupload to be seen in the url where testupload is the directory in which pdf is stored.

```
http://35.100.000.00/testupload/Materials_and_Methods_030618_AC.pdf
```

Required url is

```
http://35.100.000.00/Materials_and_Methods_030618_AC.pdf
```

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: you can do it with htaccess. for more information: http://www.htaccess-guide.com/

Comment: can you please be much more specific as i'm totally unaware of apache re_write

Comment: You should specify whether you want to do this server-side, client-side or what. Why did you tag both javascript and php?

Comment: would prefer it server side and sorry for tagging both

Comment: I recommend you to use str_replace, like `$url = str_replace('testupload/', '', 'http://35.100.000.00/testupload/Materials_and_Methods_030618_AC.pdf');` Try it here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f85b47a4bac2affaf0815b1729061c692dc40a09

Comment: @executable but then the URL will be wrong, no?

Comment: @Script47 why ? The result is the url the OP requested

Comment: @executable I believe you've misunderstood the question. They want to serve the file but without the URL changed. If we use your method, you'd get a 404.

Comment: @Script47 yes right I misunderstood the question, my bad

Answer (score -1):

> Got it to work by apache re_write rule

Comment: Answers should be more specific. See [answer].